# Get next upcoming birthday from known date in PHP

Tags: php

What is the <del>easiest</del> most efficient way to get the next birthday date when I have the date of the birth like '1983-08-15'

Currently I do something like this with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
function get_next_date($start_timestamp, $interval = 1, $time_frame = 'year'){

                                //+1 year
    $nextdate = strtotime('+'.$interval.' '.$time_frame, $start_timestamp);

       //date is still in the past
    if($nextdate - time() < 0){
         return get_next_date($nextdate);
    }

    return $nextdate;
}
```

which is not very efficient (too many recursions if date is far in the past).

I would like to have a solution where I can easily change `$interval` and `$time_frame`

EDIT:

The suggested solution `strtotime(date('d-M-', $start_timestamp).date('Y')." +{$interval} {$time_frame}")` doesn't work:

```
//(assuming today is the 2014-07-22)
1983-03-01 => 2015-03-01  //OK
1983-08-01 => 2015-08-01  //FALSE, should be 2014-08-01
```

also the function should accept a different interval to get every 10th birthday for instance:

```
1983-03-01 => 2023-03-01
1984-08-01 => 2014-08-01
```

Comment: `strtotime(date('d-M-', $start_timestamp).date('Y')." +{$interval} {$time_frame}");` Use the day and month from the start and the current year then +1 year.

Comment: `$interval`and `$time_frame` could be '2 weeks', '3 years' or '12 hours' as well. I'm searching for a more general solution

Comment: in the code example, I pass in `$interval` and `$time_frame` to strtotime. You can preface the string with a date, so that would become `22-Jul-2014 +2 weeks` for example which is perfectly valid.

Comment: got it! <del>how about hours (if I have them as well of course)?</del> OK works, please write your answer so I can accept it

Comment: @JonathanKuhn sounds like you should make this an answer :-)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn The problem is when the birthday is in the current year. I get '2015-08-01' for a birthday date of '1983-08-01'. It should be '2014-08-01'

Comment: if the start_timestamp is greater than today, then wouldn't you just use that? I mean, that would be the next birthday.

Comment: The start_timestamp is 1983-08-01 (as timestamp) so it's not greater than today but the birthday is still this year

Comment: so use two strtotime, one to get a timestamp of the date in the current year. if that is > today, use that else `strtotime("+{$interval} {$time_frame}", $first_timestamp)`.

Comment: I've updated my questions to for better explanation

Comment: There isn't an easy answer for all of this. You would need to figure out how many interval/time frames have passed between current date and start_timestamp and multiply your interval by that. For example, for `10-Feb-2014` as start date and `2 weeks` as interval, you would need to find out how many two week intervals have occurred between start_timestamp and time() and add 1 (`$newInterval`) then `strtotime("+$newInterval $time_frame", $start_timestamp)`. Essentially the calculation for `$newInterval` is the count of times your original code would recurse.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn thx, I made a function based on your suggestions. see my answer

Comment: Good. I'm glad you got it. That's pretty much what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JonathanKuhn I've made this function:

```
function get_next_date($starttime, $interval, $time_frame) {

    $now = time();

    //based on the timeframe get the amount since the $startdate
    switch ($time_frame) {
        case 'year':
            $count = date('Y', $now)-date('Y', $starttime);
            break;
        case 'month':
            $count = abs((date('Y', $now) - date('Y', $starttime))*12 + (date('m', $now) - date('m', $starttime)));
            break;
        case 'week':
            $count = floor((abs($now - $starttime)/86400)/7);
            break;
        case 'day':
            $count = floor(abs($now - $starttime)/86400);
            break;

        default:
            //if you have other time frames you should add them here
            $count = $interval;
            break;
    }

    //how often the interval should get multipled
    $times = ceil($count/$interval);

    //get the next date by counting from the starting date up until $now with the calculated interval
    $nextdate = strtotime(date('d-M-Y', $starttime)." +".($interval*$times)." {$time_frame}");

    //date is maybe in the past (but in the same year, month or week)
    if($nextdate - $now < 0){
        //add an additional interval to the expression
        $nextdate = strtotime(date('d-M-Y', $starttime)." +".($interval*$times+$interval)." {$time_frame}");
    }

    return $nextdate;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way using the DateTime class:

```
function get_next_birthday($birthday) {
    $date = new DateTime($birthday);
    $date->modify('+' . date('Y') - $date->format('Y') . ' years');
    if($date < new DateTime()) {
        $date->modify('+1 year');
    }

    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo get_next_birthday('1983-08-15');
```